# Loading Non Retina Images on a Retina Display using Asset Catalog

Tags: ios, uiimage, asset-catalog

I'm using asset catalog to manage all my app's images, and I load those images "normally" [UIImage imageNamed:@"my-image"];

What I want to do is load the non-retina version of the image from the asset catalog, on a retina display, but I can't figure out how/know if it's even possible. Any insights would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution, but only available in iOS 8:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name
               inBundle:(NSBundle *)bundle
compatibleWithTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)traitCollection
```

where

```
(UITraitCollection *)traitCollectionWithDisplayScale:(CGFloat)scale
```

So you can use:

```
// pass nil to inBundle to use the main bundle
[UIImage imageNamed:@"my-image"
           inBundle:nil
compatibleWithTraitCollection:[UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithDisplayScale:1.0]];
```